# What does the vertical bar ( | ) mean in C++?

Tags: c++, bitwise-or

I have this C++ code in one of my programming books:

```
WNDCLASSEX wndClass = { 0 };
wndClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wndClass.style =  CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
```

What does the single pipe do in C++ windows programming?

Comment: This has nothing to do with windows programming; this is a basic operator of C++.

Comment: Actually it is a operator of C, C++ adopts it

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Bitwise OR operator. It will set all bits true that are true in either of both values provided.

For example `CS_HREDRAW` could be 1 and `CS_VREDRAW` could be 2. Then it's very simple to check if they are set by using the bitwise AND operator `&`:

```
#define CS_HREDRAW 1
#define CS_VREDRAW 2
#define CS_ANOTHERSTYLE 4

unsigned int style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
if(style & CS_HREDRAW){
    /* CS_HREDRAW set */
}

if(style & CS_VREDRAW){
    /* CS_VREDRAW set */
}

if(style & CS_ANOTHERSTYLE){
    /* CS_ANOTHERSTYLE set */
}
```

See also:

- [Wikipedia: Bitwise operation (Section OR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR)
- [Wikipedia: Mask (computing) Section( Common bitmask functions)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmask#Common_bitmask_functions)

Comment: whaa..? all bits to true? so let me think. 010101 | 101010 would return 111111?

Comment: Yes. `b00010101 | b00101010` will return `b00111111`.

Answer (score 13):

In C++20, it can also be *the pipe operator of range adaptor closure objects*.
I.e. chaining together operations on ranges. Read more about it here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges#Range_adaptor_closure_objects

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxCpp check it out

Answer (score 11):

`|` is called [bitwise OR operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

`||` is called logical OR operator.

Answer (score 6):

It's a bitwise OR operator. For instance,

```
if( 1 | 2 == 3) {
    std::cout << "Woohoo!" << std::endl;
}
```

will print `Woohoo!`.